# Extract iVector from lists of MFFCs using a UBM-GMM

Tags: machine-learning, speech-recognition, google-colaboratory, python-bob

I want to do the extraction of iVector characteristics from a .txt file containing the Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficents (MFFCs). Meaning i have the MFCC extraction part I just wanted apply a universal background model/Gaussian mixture model (UBM-GMM) on this file (float) then extract the iVector using bob tool

the file contains 151000 rows and 39 column (float) I try to use the bob tool but I noticed that bob follow a complete methodology means : MFCC extraction, then application of UBM-GMM then extraction of the ivector but In my case i have the MFCC extraction part, and I just wanted apply UBM-GMM on this file then extract the iVector

This the contents of my input file (float)

```
"[ 20.412132 12.660626 -0.364722 ... 0.66215 -2.386265 -0.483279] [ 20.387691 28.921465 -7.665021 ... 4.967792 -0.837653 0.086281] [ 20.592092 26.138031 -6.041919 ... 4.59261 -1.237065 -0.047726] ... [ 17.551338 -26.566893 -8.112051 ... -1.840103 5.563478 0.753488] [ 17.538497 -25.868483 -6.84744 ... -0.072941 3.455679 -2.500857] [ 17.157589 -22.458966 -4.125641 ... 1.418648 3.925556 -3.072655]"
```

I wanted to apply to this data a UBM-GMM then extract the iVector.
As output I want another matrix of dimension lower than that given in entry which represents the iVector.

More on iVector: https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/41528.pdf

Comment: Could you provide some more background information for us to understand the question? Perhaps explaining what the data is, providing a short example of the format of the data, what your desired output is exactly, and what code you've tried so far.

Comment: @rchurt I wanted to extract the ivector characteristics from a .txt file containing the MFFC characteristics
the file contains 151000 rows and 39 column (float)
I try to use the bob tool but I noticed that bob follow a complete methodology means : MFCC extraction, then application of UBM-GMM then extraction of the ivector but In my case i have the MFCC extraction part I just wanted apply UBM-GMM on this file then extract the i vector

Comment: Could you run the command `!head <path to .txt file goes here>` (replacing with the path to you file) and edit your question to include the output?

Comment: @rchurt Nothing new :(

Comment: Did that command work, and if so can you paste the output? I'm trying to see what the file looks like so I can figure out what to do.

Comment: @rchurt this command displays the first 10 lines of a file given in parameters . I did not understand the relationship between this command and my error

Comment: Right, I don't think this will solve your problem, but I'm not sure what the data you're working with looks like, so I'm not sure how to help. If it's easier, maybe you could share an example notebook showing the data you're trying to process and the error you're getting?

Comment: @rchurt  this the contents of my file (float) " [ 20.412132  12.660626  -0.364722 ...   0.66215   -2.386265  -0.483279]
 [ 20.387691  28.921465  -7.665021 ...   4.967792  -0.837653   0.086281]
 [ 20.592092  26.138031  -6.041919 ...   4.59261   -1.237065  -0.047726]
 ...
 [ 17.551338 -26.566893  -8.112051 ...  -1.840103   5.563478   0.753488]
 [ 17.538497 -25.868483  -6.84744  ...  -0.072941   3.455679  -2.500857]
 [ 17.157589 -22.458966  -4.125641 ...   1.418648   3.925556  -3.072655] "I wanted to apply to this data ubmgmm then extract ivector.

Comment: as output it is necessary to obtain another matrix of demension lower than that given in entry which represents the ivector

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information. I edited the question to reflect what you provided, and moved it to more appropriate categories which will make it more likely that you'll get the help you need. Just for your edification, I would look at the edited version of the question--this is the level of detail (or more) that I would post in the first place so that people can help you effectively. I know that you're new so I wanted to help you out, but I don't think most other users would be so nice :)